# AWS EBS recover data from EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have this t2.micro on my aws account, after a update/reboot i can't log in to my machine thought ssh...
I have tried by aws panel, stop and start machine but nothing works...
So i created another machine with a new volume, everything is working fine..
Is it possible to attach my old volume to my new machine to copy some files? if yes there is some different config? because everytime i do i can't login

Answer (score 0):

I did it, the trick is attatch the second volume on a running instance then follow this tutorial to mount (Skip the format part)

https://devopscube.com/mount-ebs-volume-ec2-instance/